# Trying to attract certain dwellers

Tags: fallout-shelter

this is not meant to be racist in ANY way, but I'm trying to attract more black dwellers into my vault. I just keep getting white males: Usually that ratio is 9 white males to 1 white female. Does anyone have any idea why that is?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing racist about having a theme(especially if you look at the lore behind the game), but no there is no way to do this.

There are tool online that u can use to change your dwellers (including skin color).

but if you want to do it without cheating the only way is to restart the game a few times and try to get as many dwellers of your preferred skin as you can. If that's not an option due to loss of progress your only solution would be to "breed it out".

Comment: Hmm, are children fully random? I've never really paid attention...

Comment: @Nelson no their skin color is either the mothers or fathers, same goes for hair color. Hair style is random. Also the stats are similar, if both parents highest stat is strength their child will most likely also be strength based.